# External sandhi rule for final visarga followed by r?

Tags: sanskrit, sandhi

The picture at the bottom is taken from **Introduction To Sanskrit** by *Egenes Thomas,* in which we see that, if a vowel different from a or aa precedes the visarga, and if the initial lettre of the following word is r, then the visarge disappears and the preceding i or u is lengthened.
But, from [**A Sanskrit Grammar For Students** by *MacDonell, A*](https://archive.org/details/sanskritgrammarf014425mbp) we find the statement that, in the above situation, the visarga should be changed to r, as r is a soft consonant.
Therefore I am confused as to which rule is correct, and post here to know what others think about it.
This is my first post here; tell me if any inappropriate points occur, thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from using prepausal forms as the starting point. Both /s/ and /r/ become visarga pre-pausally, so Macdonnell treats /r/ as an 'etymological' exception. You get /punar api/ → [punar api/ but /devas api/ → [devo 'pi]. If the preceding vowel is /a, ā/ and the following segment is voiced, then /r/ remains [r] (except before /r/ where it is deleted). But /as/ is treated the same as /o/ (you could say that is becomes *o*, then is further changed to [a] with hiatus before a vowel, except before /a/). And /ās/ becomes [ā] before any voiced segment so /aśvās vahanti/ → *aśvā vahanti* (but /ār/ is unchanged, viz. *ahār dāmnā*). Whitney's treatment in his grammar is clearer, IMO.

[EDIT]

To clarify, "visarga" is not an underlying segment of Sanskrit, is is phonetically voiceless [h] transcribed , and derives from /r,s/. Theoretically, there could be two distinct underlying forms, /grāmayos rāmas/ or /grāmayor rāmas/. In either case, the surface outcome would be [grāmayo rāmaḥ].

The standard reference grammar of Sanskrit is *[Sanskrit Grammar](https://archive.org/details/sanskritgrammari00whituoft)*, by William Dwight Whitney.

Comment: Thanks for explaning some rules, but you didn't cover the case I am asking: for example, what would this imaginary combination be after the sandhi rules: /grāmayoh. rāmah./, where h. designates the visarga? Also, might I know the name of Whitney's grammatical treatment? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the doubts, and thanks for the link.

Comment: Be warned that Whitney's Sanskrit Grammar is very opinionated and full of idiosyncrasies. It diverges from the native grammatical tradition in many many ways.

Comment: True, but when one hopes to learn the sandhi rules, it's kind of hard to make sense of the Aṣṭādhyāyī.

Answer (score 2):

Most English books on sanskrit attempt to rephrase Panini's grammar rules and in doing so, the conciseness of the rule is lost. An additional side-effect is that it takes several sentences to explain the application of rules. This is the natural outcome of all translations - I am not finding fault with them.

Your question about the elongation of अ/इ/उ when र् is elided (or made to disappear) is governed by two rules:
`8-3-14 रो रि` and `6-3-111 ढ्रलोपे पूर्वस्य दीर्घोऽणः`

Take for example हरिः राजते meaning Hari is resplendent. The derivation always starts with

```
हरिस् + राजते
```

The suffix (or प्रत्ययः) for the nominative singular (प्रथमा-विभक्तिः एकवचनम्) is `सुँ` The उँ in सुँ gets elided due to `1-3-2 उपदेशेऽजनुनासिक इत्` and `1-3-9 तस्य लोपः` Continuing with the derivation,

```
हरिरुँ + राजते
```

Any स् at the end of a पदम् (word, defined by `1-4-14 सुप्तिङन्तं पदम्`) is replaced with रुँ by the rule `8-2-66 ससजुषो रुः`

As before, the उँ in रुँ drops and we now have

```
हरिर् + राजते
```

Now `8-3-14 रो रि` mandates elision (called लोपः) to a र् as another र् follows. This results in

```
हरि + राजते
```

Finally, whenever the elision of ढ् or र् happens, the previous अण् (i.e अ इ उ) gets elongated (called दीर्घः) So, after performing sandhi, the resulting word appears as

```
हरी राजते
```

The second rule you mentioned from MacDonell isn't in conflict with the above. `8-3-15 खरवसानयोर्विसर्जनीयः` asks to replace the र् at the end of a पदम् with विसर्गः as any letter from खर् (ख फ छ ठ थ च ट त क प) follows. As you can see, र् is not in this list of letters. An example of this rule would be as follows:

```
रामर् + चिनोति (meaning Rama collects)
```

Note that the र् at the end of राम comes from the application of `8-2-66 ससजुषो रुः` and two more rules, as explained above.

```
रामः + चिनोति
```

Further to this rule, the विसर्गः is replaced with स् by `8-3-34 विसर्जनीयस्य सः` giving rise to

```
रामस् + चिनोति
```

Finally, the स् is replaced with स् due to `8-4-40 स्तोः श्चुना श्चुः` yielding

```
रामश्चिनोति
```

Comment: Thanks for such an expounded clarification; it is quite surprising to find that the rules listed in the introductory books are in fact *composites* of some more basic rules. Thanks again.

Comment: If you are interested in sanskrit grammar, I highly recommend following http://avg-sanskrit.org/ - there are copious examples that demonstrate application of rules (and also video recordings of classes). You can leave us a note in the comments section if you have questions.

Comment: OK, I am trying to see what I can find in that site. Thanks for the recommendation. Best regards here. :)

Comment: Why do you have so many chandrabindus in your answer (e.g. सुँ instead of सु)? Generally in Devanagari the chandrabindu is used to indicate nasalization, but I get the impression you're using it for some other (what?) purpose.

Comment: Yes the chandrabindu means `anunasika` i.e nazalised vowel. Many of the pratyayas (suffixes) in Panini's grammar have nazalised vowels. This allows us to remove them by `उपदेशेऽजनुसासिक इत्`  Hence, although the pratyaya is सुँ, what remains after removing the nazalised अच् is स् Similarly in the case of रुँ etc.